# How can I keep center align images added dynamically to a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, position, width

I have a WinForms empty panel, and I'm adding images dynamically to this panel. 
To center the first image added, I just:

- Get the width (WP) of the panel and divide by 2;
- Get the width (WI) of the image and divide by 2;
- WP - WI = Left position of image X;

But I can't figure out some dinamically way to set this position when I have more than one image. Is there a way to calculate this X ? Am I right about this? Is there a easier way?

Thanks.

Comment: And that's why WPF was born :)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser @Grant. No. Only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have only one row, some where you can have a collection of `Image` objects, say

`List<Image> images`.

And method

```
void PositionImages()
{
    int totalWidth = images.Sum(img=>img.Width);
    int startX = (panel.Width - totalWidth)/2;
}
```

*Should* work to you, but you will need to check it. For example I suppose here that `tolalWidth` of all images in collection is *always* less then `panel.Width`.